# Problem understanding the external cup product

Tags: algebraic-topology

The external cup product is defined to be the map

$$ H^{k}( X ; R) \times H^{l}(Y ; R) \overset{\times}{\to} H^{k+l}(X \times Y; R)$$

where $a \times b = p_1^*(a) \smile p_2^*(b)$ where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are projections of $X \times Y$ onto $X$ and $Y$

I can't really figure out this definition.

Unfortunately, the example Hatcher uses is pretty complicated and not helpful.

Consider the space $X \times Y = S^n \times S^m$.

How do you apply this definition to the space $H^n(S^n ;R) \times H^m(S^m ;R)$ ?

Is every element in $H^{n+m}(S^n \times S^m ; R)$ a cup product of elements in $H^n(S^n ;R)$ and $H^m(S^ ;R)$ ??

How do I relate elements of $H^{n+m}(S^n \times S^m ; R)$ back to $H^n(S^n ;R)$ and $H^m(S^ ;R)$ ??

Comment: I don't see a question.

Comment: Where are you having trouble understanding the definition? The question, as of now, is too vague for anyone to help.

Comment: Questions typically begin with a word like "how", "what" or "why" and end with a question mark (?). You don't have that here.